# Jhipster GET http://localhost:9000/api/ping/{a}/{b} net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: angular, rest, api, jhipster

I am a new developer Spring Boot - Angular, currently i develop a web application using Jhispter generator. For some time i have a Java backend method that run on a longe last because of a for loop that runs 1023 iterations to test network ports of équipements. Suite to that, I found that my Observable does not receive a return of the backend and that the browser console (Chrome , Firefox, Opera) returns the net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE. After researching I tried to do asynchronous methods to keep frontend waiting for backend methode response without success.
Thanks for getting out of this impact, it's been days since I fell in love with coffee without finding an answer.

**PingComponent**
[Observable subscribe function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcgRZ.png)
[image]

**PingService**
[Observable declaration function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOJCn.png)
[image]

**@RestController**
[Spring REST API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zwwhd.png)
[image]

**Google Chrome Error**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rVo3.png)
[image]

Comment: Hi GaëlMarziou, My API call the work from swagger.

Comment: Yes the request is executed by the controller method but i get the error before the work execution done.

Comment: Have you tried setting  `{ observe: 'response' }` on http.get in PingService as all generated services do in JHipster?

Comment: i don't understand what you mean. Can you please send me an example ?

Comment: Yes normally, but the examples i finds are like do my function in PingService

Comment: Your version is probably a bit old, see https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app

Comment: Oh yes, you're right, I actually use Jhipster 4.13.0.
You think that may be the cause of my problem?
Would there be no other possible solutions than to migrate to version 5?

Comment: No need for JH 5 currently in beta, HttpClient was introduced in 4.14.0 and I'm not sure this will solve your problem

Comment: Ok Thanks @GaëlMarziou.

Comment: After Work done we have this error.
o.z.p.spring.web.advice.AdviceTrait :Internal Server Error
java.io.IOException :Une connexion etablie a ete abandonnee par un logiciel de votre ordinateur hote
.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver :Failed to invoke @ExceptionHandler method: public default org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.zalando.problem.Problem> org.zalando.problem.spring.web.advice.general.ThrowableAdviceTrait.handleThrowable(java.lang.Throwable,org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest)
java.io.IOException :UT010029: Stream is closed

Comment: Hello GaëlMarziou, I have a new about my mistake. I found that the error only occurs on port 9000 (http: // localhost: 9000) and not on port 8080 (http: // localhost: 8080). Do you know how to increase the execution time of a request on port 9000? This port is used by Webpack dev-server and BrowserSync

Comment: See https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/391#issuecomment-377003434 but it's very strange unless your PC is dog slow.